# issue reading xml file in squarespace 6 in developer mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, squarespace

i am using developer mode in square-space 6. I have jQuery custom plugin where i need to read data back and process it. My function and all its related processes are working fine on local machine but i am not able to read xml data in squarespace.

### in my plugin

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myXML.xml",
        dataType: selected_dataType,
        success: function (xml) {

            var processedXML_01 = parseXml(xml);

            $(processedXML_01).find('property').each(function () {
                     //process data..
```

many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Squarespace using folder structure, when I have put xml file in /assets folder, it works but not when i put in any other folder. I don't know the answer why!

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/assets/myXML.xml",
        dataType: selected_dataType,
        success: function (xml) {

            var processedXML_01 = parseXml(xml);
```